# Django Rest API Pagination not limiting number of objects

Tags: django-rest-framework

i followed the documentation but i still get the full list of objects not limited

views.py

```
from rest_framework.pagination import (LimitOffsetPagination,PageNumberPagination)

class PostView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object_list, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
  'PAGE_SIZE': 2
}
```

Comment: By implementing the `list` method yourself, the pagination will not work. Why do you implmement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By implementing the `list` method yourself, the pagination is no longer applied. Indeed, the [`list` method for a `ListAPIView` is implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.12.4/rest_framework/mixins.py#L37-L46):

> ```
> def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>     queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
>     page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
>     if page is not None:
>         serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
>         return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
>
>     serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
>     return Response(serializer.data)
> ```

But you thus do *not* need to implement the `list` method yourself. Your view can look like:

from rest_framework.pagination import (LimitOffsetPagination,PageNumberPagination)

```
class PostView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination

    # no list method
```